# kops unable to find kubectl binary

Tags: kubernetes

So, I've installed both kops and kubectl using the snap package manager.

```
$ which kubectl 
/snap/bin/kubectl
```

kubectl is definitely installed, however, when I run anything using kops, it complains it can't find it:

```
W1023 11:59:59.582255   27545 update_cluster.go:278] error reading kubecfg: error getting config from kubectl: error running kubectl: exec: "kubectl": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: In the meanwhile, I've installed the binary outside snap, however, I'd really like to get the snap version working.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly commands have you used? Also did you try to enter kubectl folder and export it to `PATH`?
`$ cd /snap/bin/kubectl`
`$ export PATH="$PWD:$PATH"`